# How can a neural network use both logicals and actual data?

Tags: neural-networks, matlab, binary-data, continuous-data

I am using MATLAB to train a neural network and have two different sets of inputs. One set consists of logicals (1 or 0) and the other data is actual numbers / values. For example, if the NN was for flower type, the logicals could be red or yellow and the values could be lengths of the flower petal. How can the neural network use both the values and logicals without interpreting the logicals as lengths and how would this perform? What should my architecture be?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get the question. The NN learn weights per feature, it doesn't interpret anything: that's up to the analyst only.

Comment: I'm saying that the nn will not be able to use both 0s and 1s and actual data (my lengths range from 4-6) as the inputs. It will interpret 1 and 0 as lengths so how can I describe to different that they are two different features

Comment: the logical is fine. it is interpreting it as length ( I would say position).  What you can't do is represent a categorical value as an integer ( eg job type as 1,2,3,...), you have to turn into logicals (ie one hot encoding).  first think about how it would work in  linear regression.

Comment: This question is based on a misunderstanding (which is what CV is for), but it isn't too unclear to be answered. In fact, it has been answered in the comment above & in the answer below. I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: @gung it's still unclear imo, _"How can the neural network use both the values and logicals without interpreting the logicals as lengths and how would this perform?"_. It's up to the poster to clarify the meaning of the question, but as it stands, I'm not even sure how to begin answering it.

Comment: @seanv507 _"it is interpreting it as length"_: the logical feature increases/decreases the probability assigned to a given class (in the example, flower types), it has nothing to do with length, another separate feature altogether.

Comment: @firebug I interpreted the question as essentially-how do I put logical into an nn which takes real numbers (lengths, mass, widths etc). Basically does it make sense to treat a logical as another dimension in a real vector space)(and its that 'length' i was referring to). I think the op understood that you can put inputs of different units (cm, kg, km/h etc)

Comment: @seanv507 I'm not really sure where you got that impression, since the OP explicitly asks _"How can the neural network use both the values and logicals without interpreting the logicals as lengths [...]?"_ after mentioning petal lengths in the line above.

Comment: @seanv507 and in the comment in the answer below: _" But since the nn knows no units how does it know that 1 and 0 aren't just flower lengths?"_

Answer (score 2):

For neural nets it doesn't matter what does the figures represent. Binary feature could be gender, color or anything else, it doesn't matter. Only the values matter. By the way, actual numbers also could mean anything, neural net simply learns the best weights for features.

Comment: But since the nn knows no units how does it know that 1 and 0 aren't just flower lengths?

Comment: Because technically there is no difference between continuous and binary variables. In any case you have a vector of values X and a vector of weights W and multiply them. Neural net simply tries to optimize loss function and minimize the error.